# Checking if one date is greater than the other using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to check if one date is greater than another date using google script. 
I am extracting a date from the spreadsheet and formatting it. Then I check it against today's date. If today's date is less than the extracted date, some functionality has to be done.This is as far as I have got.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //activating a particular sheet
var data = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, sheet1.getLastRow(), 100).getValues();

for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    var todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    var dueDate = new Date(data[row][17]);
    //Logger.log("Due: "+dueDate);
    var nRow = row+1;
    dueDate.setDate(dueDate.getDate()+1);
    var curDate=Utilities.formatDate(dueDate, "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    //Logger.log("Current: "+curDate);

    if(curDate>todayDate){
        Logger.log("Today: "+todayDate);
        Logger.log("Current: "+curDate);
        Logger.log("In");
    }
 }
```

I am able to log the values but the `if()` statement does not seem to work. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem got solved. Solution was:

`if(curDate.valueOf()>todayDate.valueOf()){}`

It is now working.

Comment: yes, referring to [this method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp)